# Error loading data on tabulator with AJAX only on ipad

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, tabulator

I have a php server with symfony 3.4 installed i have made an application where people can connect and send an order use tabulator. 
All works great on PC and on all other mobile device like (iphone) but it doesn't work on ipad.
I really don't know why. I have found on the net that ipad has a problem with cache and AJAX call but i don't know how to deactivate cache on tabulator configuration.

That's tabulator initialize (I have removed list of columns and callbacks because it's really long, they works with all other system so i think that's not the problem):

```js
 table = new Tabulator("#tabellaOrdinazione", {
    height: ($(window).height() - $("#inizioContenuti").position().top) + "px",
    ajaxURL: Routing.generate('agente_ordine_nuovo_lista_ajax', {
                codiceCliente:  $("#codiceClienteTxt").val()
            }),
    ajaxProgressiveLoad:"scroll",
    ajaxProgressiveLoadScrollMargin:300,
    ajaxFiltering:true,
    ajaxSorting:true,
    layout:"fitDataFill",
    placeholder: "No data!",
    columns:[
```

EDIT: I have just tried to change the cache with no-cache like attached code but the results is the same. Working on all devices except iPad

```js
 table = new Tabulator("#tabellaOrdinazione", {
            height: ($(window).height() - $("#inizioContenuti").position().top) + "px",
            ajaxURL: Routing.generate('agente_ordine_nuovo_lista_ajax', {
                        codiceCliente:  $("#codiceClienteTxt").val()
                    }),
            ajaxProgressiveLoad:"scroll",
            ajaxProgressiveLoadScrollMargin:300,
            ajaxFiltering:true,
            ajaxSorting:true,
            ajaxConfig: {
                cache: 'no-cache',
                credentials: 'same-origin'
            },
            layout:"fitDataFill",
            placeholder: "No data!",
            columns:[
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem with JQUERY Ajax. 
I have override the Request promise of Tabulator and i have added a JQUERY ajax for loading data from my server and now also ipad works.

Here's the code:

```js
function ottieniDatiRicerca(url, config, params){
            //url - the url of the request
            //config - the ajaxConfig object
            //params - the ajaxParams object

            //return promise
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
               $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: 'html',
                    url: url + "?params=" + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(params)),
                    async: true,
                    success: function (response) {
                        resolve(JSON.parse(response));
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        reject("Status: " + textStatus);
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        function inizializzaTabulator(){
            table = new Tabulator("#tabellaOrdinazione", {
            height: ($(window).height() - $("#inizioContenuti").position().top) + "px",
            ajaxURL: Routing.generate('agente_ordine_nuovo_lista_ajax', {
                        codiceCliente:  $("#codiceClienteTxt").val()
                    }),
            ajaxProgressiveLoad:"scroll",
            ajaxProgressiveLoadScrollMargin:300,
            ajaxFiltering:true,
            ajaxSorting:true,
            ajaxRequestFunc:ottieniDatiRicerca,
            layout:"fitDataFill",
            placeholder: "No data!",
            columns:[
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be due to lack of fetch compatibility on the iPad,

have you tried including the [Fetch Polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) before the Tabulator library